# Metaio Change Geometry Texture

Tags: 3d, geometry, textures, metaio

I have tried to load a 3D model with its texture in metaio sdk. But now i have a new challenge:
Suppose that i have a 3D car model, i want to load it in [Metaio](http://dev.metaio.com) sdk and change color of the car when user taps the screen.
How can do that?
In general, what is the relationship between a 3d model and its texture? Can we have a **single** 3d model and **multiple** textures for it, and bind them at runtime? How?
Thanks.

Comment: are you referring to the android SDK of metaio?

Comment: Yes, Paizo. Metaio Android SDK 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can have multiple texture by using `setTexture` of the `IGeometry` object.

Depending on the type of the model you are using the texture can be stored in the model itself or in a file with the same name. When I tried multiple texture stored in a MDL file it didn't worked and I had to store them separately.

your code would be something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onGeometryTouched(IGeometry geometry) {
    MetaioDebug.log("Template.onGeometryTouched: " + geometry);

    geometry.setTexture(AssetsManager.getAssetPathAsFile(getApplicationContext(), "mytexture.png"));
}
```

to handle the touch if you don't already have you should register a gesture handler:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //other init code here...

    mGestureMask = GestureHandler.GESTURE_ALL;
    mGestureHandler = new GestureHandlerAndroid(metaioSDK, mGestureMask);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer **Paizo**. Just **another question**. How can i save texture of a model into one png file? Every side of my model should have different textures...

Comment: you need a tool for doing that, for `mdl` files I used q2modeler and for that type of models the texture is one for all the "faces". I didn't used other model formats so I can't help, it seems possible reading [here](http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/6121/model-export-from-maya.html) `if you export to OBJ or FBX multiple textures per scene are fine as long as they're not layered but only 1 texture per material.` I suppose you can achieving that by using a different material per face with its own texture.